# In Windbg how to get the whole content from !do Command

Tags: .net, memory, windbg, sos

I'm currently working in a memory issue on a .NET application, I'm debugging the Issue using Windbg I have come across to what the memory issue is, but during the investigation `!do` command is getting me the object which has a content that is excessive large BUT the Content that gets displayed by the command is truncated, Is there a way that I can get the Content in its entirely from the `!do` command?

The result of the command looks something like this:

```
0:000> !do [Address]
Name:        System.Byte[]
MethodTable: ...
EEClass:     ...
Size:        1048600(0x100018) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 1048576, Type Byte
Content:     [This is the content that its getting truncated]
Fields:
None
```

Comment: Do you have to use `!do` or can you use `!da` to dump the array?

Comment: I should be able to use !da, what's the difference?

Comment: `!da` will give you the addresses of the elements so that you can then do a `!do` on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a `byte` array you can use `db` to dump out the raw memory.  I created a `byte` array with values 0, 1, 2, ... 2000 and dumped it out:

```
0:000> !do 0x020a3560
Name:        System.Byte[]
MethodTable: 73504588
EEClass:     7319229c
Size:        2012(0x7dc) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 2000, Type Byte
Content:     ................................ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~.
Fields:
None
```

```
0:000> db 0x020a3560 0x020a3560+07dc
020a3560  88 45 50 73 d0 07 00 00-00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07  .EPs............
020a3570  08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f-10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17  ................
020a3580  18 19 1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f-20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27  ........ !"#$%&'
020a3590  28 29 2a 2b 2c 2d 2e 2f-30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37  ()*+,-./01234567
020a35a0  38 39 3a 3b 3c 3d 3e 3f-40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47  89:;?@ABCDEFG
020a35b0  48 49 4a 4b 4c 4d 4e 4f-50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57  HIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW
020a35c0  58 59 5a 5b 5c 5d 5e 5f-60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67  XYZ[\]^_`abcdefg
020a35d0  68 69 6a 6b 6c 6d 6e 6f-70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77  hijklmnopqrstuvw
020a35e0  78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f-80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87  xyz{|}~.........
020a35f0  88 89 8a 8b 8c 8d 8e 8f-90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97  ................
...(snip)...
```

The first 4 bytes are the method table (73504588), and the next 4 bytes are the length of the array (0x07D0, or 0n2000).  Then all the bytes after that are the data.

Comment: How did came up with the 0x020a3560+07d0? what was the conversion from "Size: 2012(0x7dc)" to "0x07D0" and the Method table from 73504588 to 0x020a3560?

Comment: Oops, it really should be `0x7DC` (2012, the size of the whole object) and not `0x7D0` (2000, the number of elements in the array).  I didn't use the MethodTable at all, just the object's address (which you implied you had in the question).  I was just noting that's what those first 4 bytes are when you dump out the array.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Patrick is ok for Byte[] or other simple types. If you need the same for reference types, try `!da` of `SOS` or `!mdt` of the `SOSEX`extension.

First, let's see how `!da` works:

```
0:077> *** Get method table to be specific about the object
0:077> !dumpheap -stat -type PointF[]
total 290 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
7ae3a114      290         8360 System.Drawing.PointF[]
Total 290 objects

0:077> *** Get individual arrays
0:077> !dumpheap -mt 7ae3a114
 Address       MT     Size
3be693a4 7ae3a114       28     
3be69400 7ae3a114       28   
...
total 290 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
7ae3a114      290         8360 System.Drawing.PointF[]
Total 290 objects

0:077> *** Pick one for demo purposes. Output is not that useful.
0:077> !do 3be693a4 
Name: System.Drawing.PointF[]
MethodTable: 7ae3a114
EEClass: 7adeb1cc
Size: 28(0x1c) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 2, Type VALUETYPE
Element Type: System.Drawing.PointF
Fields:
None

0:077> *** Dump contents of the array
0:077> !da 3be693a4 
Name: System.Drawing.PointF[]
MethodTable: 7ae3a114
EEClass: 7adeb1cc
Size: 28(0x1c) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 2, Type VALUETYPE
Element Methodtable: 7ae3c3ac
[0] 3be693ac
[1] 3be693b4
```

Now, you typically want more details about the two objects in the array. You could fiddle around with the `.foreach` command, but there's no `-short` option, so go the simpler way using `!mdt`:

```
0:077> .load D:\debug\Extensions\sosex\4\32\sosex.dll

0:077> !mdt -e:2 3be693a4
3be693a4 (System.Drawing.PointF[], Elements: 2, ElementMT=7ae3c3ac)
[0] (System.Drawing.PointF) VALTYPE (MT=7ae3c3ac, ADDR=3be693ac)
    x:0.000000 (System.Single)
    y:-1.000000 (System.Single)
[1] (System.Drawing.PointF) VALTYPE (MT=7ae3c3ac, ADDR=3be693b4)
    x:1917.000000 (System.Single)
    y:22.000000 (System.Single)
increase depth
```

Update: PointF was not the best example, because it is also a value type, but it's similar for reference types.