# How to run .foreach on a managed array addresses in WInDBG?

Tags: .net, windbg

The `!DumpArray` command does not have the **-short** flag like `!DumpHeap`. Now, I have an array of objects, i.e. an array of addresses. How can one iterate over all of them using `.foreach` (or any other way)?

I can probably treat the array as an unmanaged object - figure out the layout and get to the contiguous memory part where the 64 bits addresses are stored. But I really hope there is a better way.

Comment: Here's a description on how to do it manually: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/04/30/arrays-and-sos/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25531782/480982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up noticing that a managed array of 64 bits pointers have its items start at the offset 0x10.

So, the code to iterate over the items would be:

```
.foreach /pS1 /ps1 (x {dq /c1 <The Array Address>+0x10 L<Count>}){.echo x }
```

Where **<The Array Address>** is the array address and **<Count>** is the count of array items to visit.

In my case, I actually deal with a `List<T>` object. It contains the array reference at the offset 8 (_items) and the count of items at the offset 0x18 (_size)

So, given X the address of a `List<T>` object, where T is a reference type in a 64 bits system, we can iterate the items of the list like this:

```
r @$t0 = wo(X+0x18)
.foreach /pS1 /ps1 (x {dq /c1 poi(X+8)+0x10 L@$t0}){.echo x }
```

Comment: You could also try !sosex.mdt -e:{level}. This will allow you to expand an array and even to look at the fields of each object.

Comment: I need to do a certain action on each address. `.echo` is just an example.